# How to correctly get output from dialog in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I tried to find answers to my question on the internet, but no answer satisfied me enough. I am writing WPF application and i'm trying to implement dialog mechanism. I have a simple ViewModel, and when some event happens, i would like to show a dialog, collect some output data from it and store it in "parent" View Model.
My method in a view model looks like this:

```
    private void Expand()
    {

        ...

        catch(ArgumentNullException)
        {

            Shrink();

            var errorDialogVM = new DialogVM(new Dialog() { Type = DialogType.Error, Message = $"Unauthorized access to \"{FileManager.GetDirectoryName(Path)}\" directory!" });

            DialogService.ShowDialog(errorDialogVM);

            //Here i need output from dialog

        }

    }
```

Implementation of ShowDialog method:

```
    public void ShowDialog(DialogVM dialogVM)
    {

        var dialog = new DialogBox();
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;

        dialog.DataContext = dialogVM;

        dialog.Owner = mainWindow;

        dialog.Show();

    }
```

Now, let's imagine that i need some data from the dialog. How can i pass it to my ViewModel in a proper way?

Comment: Why not create a property in the view model for the data you want to store?

Comment: Well, the problem is i am using ViewModel of my Dialog in parent-ViewModel class. I would like to get some Data provided by user, stored in dialog-ViewModel in parent-ViewModel (after calling ShowDialog, like "ParentProperty = errorDialogVM.Data;" After calling ShowDialog method, Expand() continues executing and the input data is not even created yet. I need some idea to inform parentVM that data is ready to catch and somehow deliver it to the VM.

Comment: View model shouldn't handle view elements. A dialog is a view element. A better solution would be to 1. Catch the exception 2. Raise an error event with an error model as event args 3. The view that has registered to the error event shows a dialog to collect user input and stores them in the previously received error model 4. View executes a command on the view model to pass back the error model 5. View model can process the error model (user input).

Comment: You can add a `DialogDataReady` event to your dialog view model. The parent view model can subscribe to this event and handle it. But as I said before this is not good design as it violates MVVM. You introduced a dependency to your view by handling dialogs inside your view models. I think it's absolutely not necessary and very cheap to avoid. See my answer. I tried to show some alternatives that are not violating MVVM.

Comment: Dialog Boxes are problematic with MVVM, but it can be done. You might want to read [my article about this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM), I've provided a library too that makes it all much easier.

Comment: Worth considering the purpose of mvvm is not some end in itself. You could define an interface iShowSomeDialog. Inject a piece of code does that at run time by showing some view and passing data back to a bound command when the user clicks something. When testing the class injected satisfying that interface has no ui dependencies. Which then still allows you to run tests without instantiating UI and perhaps offers a less obscure way to handle such a requirement. I would suggest this is not "breaking mvvm" because the viewmodel doesn't have any dependency on any UI.

Comment: @Andy By injecting an interface `IShowSomeDialog` that shows a dialog into the view model, you also inject a dependency to UI elements or code. As `IShowSomeDialog` has to reference UI so has the view model. You can't deploy the view model (create an instance of it) without satisfying those implicit dependencies (except you mock it away, which would eliminate the behavior). Using events or binding with dedicated dialog view models is _really_ decoupling the view model from the UI regarding code and logic and not just hiding the dependency behind a constructor injection or implicit invocations

Comment: @Andy I mean showing a dialog is in the domain of the view. You are therefore explicitly injecting view into the view model.

Comment: @BionicCode Kind of the point of interfaces is you do not have a concrete dependency.  So no. I'm not introducing a dependency on UI. It's a dependency on an interface that returns data. That can be injected for automated testing so no ui needs to be instantiated.

Comment: @Andy Yes, but that's only half of the story. You don't depend on the implementation of this interface directly. You _inverted_ the dependency on class level and on module or component level. But only when the view component (or module) hosts and instantiates the implementation. But what I mean is that the implementation is still part of the dependency graph although the dependency arrow now points into the right direction and there is no direct edge between the nodes, it is still part of the same graph - as well as the dependencies of the implementation.

Comment: @Andy This becomes evident when looking at the graph (or class diagram with dependencies). If you use binding or events then the object is totally removed from the dependency graph of the view model's component or module. That's the main goal of MVVM. To invert the dependencies you don't need MVVM but Dependency Inversion.

Comment: @BionicCode Seriously mate? If an interface just returns data it has no dependency on UI or object graph or any of that stuff you wrote. And satisfies the main purpose of MVVM - discrete instantiation for testing

Comment: @Andy No problem. this wasn't meant to be an offense. When I test my view model code I don't  need to mock away UI stuff like show dialog logic. My point was that your interface is hiding UI logic like displaying a dialog. In my understanding I can query user input or display messages without having my view model to know that user interaction is required which is obviously part of the UI (in my understanding). That's why I can test without  mocking dialog logic like a `IDialogService` etc. I can witness that no _dependency_ in form of a `IDialogService` needs to be injected into my view model.

Comment: @Andy  To my understanding moving dialog logic from the view model into a separate class can be called encapsulation. Encapsulation doesn't decouple. I just wanted to say that required logic is possible without introducing any extra dependency at all. To me it's a severe design problem on different level. The view model should not depend on data to operate on the model. I mean having the view model to _wait_ for user input is absolute bad design. The command pattern indicates this. The view triggers the actions offered by a view model.

Comment: @Andy The `ICommand` pattern includes a `CanExecute` member to ensure that the action is executed in a valid data context. Data validation ensures that no invalid data is stored in the view model. If an action has to be aborted e.g. internet connection is missing the view model throws an exception or raises an event. Like common data validation the UI (user) has to fix problems and retry to execute the action. Don't see no need for the view model to _wait_ for data. A dialog always means "waiting for user input".

Comment: @Andy That's why I am convinced that the problem _has_ to be solved without introducing any extra dependency to any kind of dialog service at all.

Answer (score 1):

View model shouldn't handle view elements. A dialog is a view element.
The view model can trigger user input by raising and event e.g., an error event with an data model as event args. The view that has registered to the event shows a dialog to collect user input and stores them in the previously received data model. The view then executes a command on the view model to pass back the data model.

Instead of an event you can also bind the view to a property of the view model e.g. of type `bool`. On property change show the dialog and return the result using a `ICommand`.

Alternatively let the view model expose a flag e.g. `HasException` and a property `ExceptionDialogModel` which can be used to bind a custom dialog or form. Then create a simple modal dialog yourself:

**ExampleDialog**

```
<Grid x:Name="ExampleDialog"
      Visibility="Visible"
      Panel.ZIndex="100"
      VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Rectangle Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=ActualWidth}"
             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=ActualHeight}"
             Fill="Gray"
             Opacity="0.7" />
  <Grid Width="400"
        Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Background="LightGray"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
      <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5"
                          Color="Black"
                          Opacity="0.6" />
      </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Margin="30"
               Text="I am a modal dialog and my Visibility or Opacity property can be easily modified by a trigger or a nice animation" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Height="50">
      <Button x:Name="OkButton"
              Content="Ok"
              Width="80" />
      <Button x:Name="CancelButton"
              Margin="30,0,30,0"
              Content="Cancel"
              Width="80" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
  <Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ExampleDialog"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                         Duration="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

You can put the `Grid` anywhere in your `Window` and toggle the `Visibility`. It will overlay the parent `Window` and has modal behavior.
Bind the `DataContext` to the `ExceptionDialogModel` so that the data is send back via `TwoWay` binding. Use  a command to trigger a retry procedure (e.g., an *OK* or *Retry* button).
The `Visibility` can bind to the `HasException` property. You can animate this dialog and give it any look and feel you like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing this backwards. You should pass reference to your view model to the dialog, not the other way around because view model should be separate and not aware of the view's mechanics. Dialog, on the other hand, knows which properties of view model it needs to set. So it will be something like the following:

```cs
public class MyDialog : Dialog
{
    public MyDialog(DialogVM ViewModel) {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContex = ViewModel;
        // TODO: Bind to view model's properties in XAML or set them on OnClose()
    }
}
```